# Windows split into bootable/non-bootable drives

Tags: windows, ssd, nvme

Hardware is a DELL Workstation with BIOS/MBR and UEFI boot capability, no NVMe support though. The drive in question is a hardware RAID card Highpoint SSD7120 with 4 U.2 SSD drives. The mainboard also has normal SATA ports available, one of which is routed to a CFast2.0 slot. Drivers for the SSD7120 are available for Windows and Linux (and OSX), but the controller has no native boot support.

I did successful tests with virtualization under Fedora, with the OS residing on a CFast card, and having the SSD7120 as the main storage for VMs, including different Windows versions as well as OSX and Linux, including GPU virtualization.

While the VM tests were interesting, and definitely the way to go for a server, I want to settle for a bare-metals Windows 10 installation for day-to-day use as a Workstation, and was wondering how I could make the most use out of the very fast SSD7120 controller, and have as little of Windows installed on a SATA drive as possible.

Obviously direct installation on the RAID volume isn't possible. I was first thinking that it should be possible to only put the Windows bootloader on the bootable SATA drive, together with drivers for the hardware RAID controller, but that seems to not be how the Windows boot process works. Please correct me if I'm wrong. So then the question is, how much of Windows (C:\ProgramData, C:\Program Files, C:\Users, C:\Windows, ...) could you put on a separate drive, how would you distribute drive letters (C:\Windows vs D:\Windows) and how would one go about that? I'm also open to other ideas, alternative boot loaders, etc.

**TLDR: I want to put as little of Windows as possible on a bootable SATA drive, in order to have the most benefit from a very fast non-bootable drive as the main disk.**

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I accepted that Windows needs to live on a bootable partition, not only the bootloader, and redirected most directories to the secondary drive via junctions.

For this, I made a Windows USB installation media, used it to access a command prompt, used pnputil -a driver.inf to load the RAID driver and executed this:

```
xcopy C:\Users\ D:\Users\ /S /E /Y /O /K /H /B 
rename C:\Users C:\_Users
mklink /J C:\Users D:\Users
```

Also for C:\Program Files, C:\Program Files (x86), C:\ProgramData. Disabling hibernation via powercfg -H OFF and moving the page file to the secondary drive as well, and C:\ is pretty much only the Windows installation itself. I had to fix a few junctions in "Default User" and "ProgramData" afterwards manually.

It would also be possible to junction select folders inside C:\Windows to the secondary drive, and as long as they are not essential during boot, the machine would still be okay even without the secondary drive.

While not the cleanest solution, it is very flexible, and would with symbolic links instead of directory junctions probably also work with UNC paths.